# How is this C++ identifier undefined?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Alright, so I'm trying to learn C++, and I've got two objects that are both subclasses("testgame") of a parent class("game"). Here are the definitions of both:

```
//game.h
#pragma once
#include <string>
class game
{
public:
    virtual ~game() {

    }
    virtual std::string getTitle() = 0;
    virtual bool setup() = 0;
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
};
```

And testgame

```
//testgame.h
#pragma once
#include "game.h"
#include <iostream>
class testgame :
    public game
{
public:
    std::string name;

    testgame(std::string name) {
        this->name = name;
    }
    ~testgame() {
        std::cout << name << " is being destroyed..." << std::endl;
        delete this;
    }
    bool setup() {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    void start() {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
    void update() {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
    std::string getTitle() {
        return name;
    }
};
```

Now, when I try to do this:

```
#include "game.h"
#include "testgame.h"
...
game* game = new testgame("game1");
game* game2 = new testgame("game2");
...
```

`game2` has an error saying that `game2` is undefined. But, if I comment out `game`'s declaration, the error goes away. Can someone help me figure out what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Explain this to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging): `game* game = new testgame("game1");`

Comment: In addition to what was said above: Please **copy-paste** errors, not paraphrase them.

Comment: Note that `delete this` in the deconstructor is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, naming variables the same as types will result in rather confusing parses.

```
game* game = new testgame("game1");
```

Now `game` is a value. So the second line parses as, believe it or not, multiplication.

```
(game * game2) = new testgame("game2");
```

which is understandably nonsense. Hence, `game2` is a name that doesn't exist and we're trying to "multiply" by it. Simply name your variable `game1` or anything that isn't a type and it will work out.

Comment: Wow. I'd have never have thought that could be the case. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Aaaand that's also a hint why you should use naming conventions - e.g. name all classes CamelCase and all temp vars lowerCamelCase. By doing so, such errors happen less often: e.g. Game* game